# How do you concatenate text when using Bind expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, syntax, binding

What is the syntax to concatenate text into a binding expression for an asp.net webpage (aspx).

For example if I had a hyperlink that was being bound like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkID" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Link") %>' Target="_blank" 
                        Text="View" runat="server"/>
```

How do you change, say, the Text to concatenate a bound value with a string?  Variations like this aren't quite right.

```
Text='<%# Bind("ID") + " View" %>'
```

neither does

```
Text='<%# String.Concat(Bind("ID"), " View") %>'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also place the "concatenation" in the text portion of a tag if using a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="sortName">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbName" runat="server" OnClick="lbName_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
         <%--Enter any text / eval bindind you want between the tags--%>
         <%# Eval("Name") %> (<%# Eval("ID") %>)
   </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This results in output like:

Name (ID)

inside of the template column.

Answer (score 36):

Use Eval instead.

```
Text='<%# Eval("ID", "{0} View") %>'
```

Eval is also better if the value is not going to be updated, where Bind allows two way data binding.

Comment: For this question, Eval is correct since there's no point in doing two-way databinding in the NavigateUrl property

Answer (score 3):

I have used `String.Format("{0}{1}"`... before to good effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
CommandArgument='<%#String.Format("{0}|{1}", Eval("ArgZero"), Eval("ArgOn"))%>'
```