# Composition of data and text in alternatetext tag in Image control

Tags: asp.net

I want to have a alternatetext tag in Image control . I want to combine text and data in alternatetext tag .

how can I do this ?

```
AlternateText='Sample + <%# Eval("fSubject") %>'
```

this is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this answer on SO.

[How do you concatenate text when using Bind expression in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360851/how-do-you-concatenate-text-when-using-bind-expression-in-asp-net)

Check at the bottom of the following article.  At the very bottom, it using example with AlternateText field being concatenated.

http://www.sedh.gr/tutorials/web_dev/ASPNET2/ASPNET07/aspnet07-05.html

```
<asp:Image Width="40" Runat="Server"
        AlternateText='<%# "Picture of " & Eval("ItemNumber") %>'
        ImageUrl='<%# "../Pictures/" & Eval("ItemNumber") & ".jpg" %>'/>
```

Comment: Dear Mitul , your answer is correct but replace & with + . by + works correctly . thanks .